# How to pass a pointer to a structure to a function that is described in a different header?

Tags: c, structure

I declared and defined the structure in separate files and from main I access them without problems, but when I try to pass a pointer to the structure in functions that in turn are also declared and defined in other files, there is a problem:

```
In file included from func.c:1: func.h:4:22: warning: ‘struct StrA’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
    4 |     void func(struct StrA *usrSet);
      |                      ^~~~ func.c:5:6: error: conflicting types for ‘func’
    5 | void func(struct StrA *usrSet){
      |      ^~~~ In file included from func.c:1: func.h:4:10: note: previous declaration of ‘func’ was here
    4 |     void func(struct StrA *usrSet);
      |          ^~~~
```

Here is the code of the working sample:

```
//main.c
//------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include "str.h"
#include "func.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    myStr.a = 4;
    myStr.b = 3;
    printf("%d %d\n", myStr.a, myStr.b);

    return 0;
}

//str.h
//-------------------------------
#ifndef STR_H
#define STR_H
struct StrA
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

extern struct StrA myStr;

#endif

//str.c
//----------------
#include "str.h"

struct StrA myStr;
```

But if you add a function (also described in another block) and try to pass it a pointer to the structure as an argument, we will get the error described above.

```
//main.c 
//-----------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include "str.h"
#include "func.h"
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    func(&myStr);

    printf("%d %d\n", myStr.a, myStr.b);

    return 0;
}

//func.h
//-----------------
#ifndef FUNC
#define FUNC

void func(struct StrA *usrSet);

#endif

//func.c
//----------------
#include "func.h"
#include "str.h"

struct StrA myStr;
void func(struct StrA *usrSet){

    myStr.a = 1;
    myStr.b = 9;
}
```

They all include mutually related. str.h and str.c I do not describe them again, not to increase post, they remained unchanged. Whether there is a universal and correct way to connect to the external side of the structure being described with the ability to take them as a pointer. This example is artificially simplified to make it easier to understand what I want.

Comment: Are you trying to program C or C++? This is one area where the two languages differ.

Comment: Not sure if this is an oversimplification or not, so I'll ask in a comment: how does `func.h` know what `StrA` is? That structure is referenced in that file, but not declared from there.

Comment: Have you considered that the compiler will process the header `func.h` before than `str.h` where the structure is defined? Invert the two includes in module `func.c` and it will work.

Comment: Where is `struct strA` defined in the second code??

Comment: The warning tells you exactly what your problem is -- fix that and your problem goes away. Add `struct StrA;` just before the declaration of `func` in func.h